# References for Convex Optimization

Tags: reference-request, convex-optimization

This is a bit of an odd question, but I'm looking for a good reference for convex optimization. I would like to see everything proved, and I'm not particularly interested in algorithms and the like. What I'm hoping to see is a bit of an elucidation of the structure of the theory rather than the mechanical aspects. I've looked at both Boyd's and Bertsekas's books and found them, for lack of a better term, ugly. I couldn't shake the feeling that there must be a better way to state many of these results.

So, at the risk of offending various people in the field, is there a book that makes convex optimization beautiful?

Comment: Why ugly, exactly?

Comment: That's why this is such a bad question ... it's hard to describe, and I resisted asking this question for a long time because of it. But I thought I'd give it a shot, and maybe people can answer with what they think is beautiful math.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1209065/339790)

Comment: I guess one thing I’m interested in is abstracting the setting where convex optimization is performed. One half-baked idea I had reading some texts is to try abstract the notion of a hyperplane. Then you get a map from the space of sets to subsets of the space of hyperplanes given by the set of hyperplanes that contain the original set. There’s a backwards map given by the intersection of all the hyperplanes. Cont’d.

Comment: Closed convex sets are the sets that are preserved under the composition of these two maps. I’d then try to rephrase the usual theorems in this context. I have no idea of this is a productive line of thinking, but it’s the sort of thing I’m interested in.

Answer (score 1):

In Chapter $2$ of *[Nonlinear Programming: Theory and Algorithms](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Nonlinear+Programming%3A+Theory+and+Algorithms%2C+3rd+Edition-p-9780471486008)* by Mokhtar S. Bazaraa et al, they explore what I consider to be the best way to depict convexity for Optimization models. They explore convexity under the notion of defining everything as sets and hyperplanes, and they explore quite a few theorems and lemmas like the *Carathbodory* theorem (much more than I have read in other [non-linear books](https://carmamaths.org/resources/jon/Preprints/Books/CaNo2/cano2f.pdf)), and provide examples for each introduced idea in some truly elegant forms. Their diagrams and examples, like the following one regarding polar cones:

[image]

actually was significantly helpful for me in getting some concepts across that previous textbooks I have read, or past courses I've taken, didn't do too well. Truly, the whole book is good enough beyond this chapter, enough so that it should be always on the bookshelves of those who are into optimization theory.